# Carotene in Dracaena draco

Tags: trees, heat

I'll keep this question straight and simple:

Some succulent plants produce carotene, a red pigment, in response to great heat, turning their leaves red. The dragon blood tree (*Dracaena* *draco*) is among the succulent plants. Does it exhibit this behaviour too?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they do.

[What We Know and What We Do Not Know about Dragon Trees?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjMwdGO2p3pAhVL5awKHUvbDxMQFjACegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F1999-4907%2F11%2F2%2F236%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw0jYKLmh_FJAUw-2QlnM0Pq)

> Numerous phytochemical studies of resins from the Dracaena species
>   resulted in the isolation and subsequent identification of sterols
>   [135–138], steroidal saponins [110,138–141], lignans [138], and
>   terpenoids [131,135,142–144], flavonoids (recently reviewed by Sun et
>   al. [129], bioflavonoids [145,146], carotenoids [109,138], and
>   aromatic compounds [107,147–151].

Citations are behind a paywall but apparently carotenoids are in the sap.